# Is there a way to compare two strings where one is the parent string and the other a child string and make bold similar substrings?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have two strings that look like this:

```
$string1 = "aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee, ffff, gggg";
$string2 = "aaaa, ffff";
```

I have extracted these strings by employing the function [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) in PHP and then imploding the resultant arrays into these two strings.

I would like to have elements in $string2 that appear in $string1 echoed out in bold without removing any element in $string1. For example i would like to have the following result echoed out in HTML:

**aaaa**, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee, **ffff**, gggg

I have implemented the following solution:

```
$array1 = explode(',', $string2):
foreach($array1 as $t){
   $string1= str_replace($t,'<b>'. $t.'</b>',$string1);
}
echo "$string1";
```

My solution works but i would like to know if there is a better/efficient/cleaner way of achieving this using PHP?

Comment: Honestly, it would probably be _way_ easier to do while you still have arrays, before imploding them into strings.

Comment: Exactly how are you deriving the two strings? What are you [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)-ing? What are you starting with?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I am array intersecting a series of arrays out-putted by SQL queries from different related tables. I am starting with an array that outputs `$string1` (after imploding) and then i run an `array_intersect_key` combined with `array_flip`  on results outputted by a second SQL query to derive `$string2`

Comment: @rickdenhaan please expound

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting it. Can you provide, in your question, both SQL query's resulting arrays you are working with to derive `$string1` and `$string2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)-ing the strings back into arrays, so the longer string can be iterated and checking the short string, with [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), for any matching items:

```
$string1 = "aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee, ffff, gggg";
$string2 = "aaaa, ffff";

$array1 = explode(", ", $string1);
$array2 = explode(", ", $string2);
$array3 = [];
foreach ( $array1 as $val ) {
    if ( in_array($val, $array2) ) {
        array_push($array3, "<strong>$val</strong>");
    }
    else {
        array_push($array3, $val);
    }
}
$string3 = implode(", ", $array3);
```

Try it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/431ec

Comment: Thank you. This is even better and cleaner than my solution..